# only alphabet in firstname and lastname in customer registration form Magento 2

Tags: magento2, form-validation, customer-registration

How can i add validations for only alphabets in First name and Last name fields in Customer registration form?

Comment: I tried your code but it is not working for the website. I also want only alphabets in the First name and Last name fields in the Customer registration form. Please let me know if you any other solution for this. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extend **name.phtml** file in your theme as below and add **letters-only** validation:-

```
app\design\frontend\VendorName\themename\Magento_Customer\templates\widget\name.phtml
```

First Name:-

```
<input type="text" id="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFieldId('firstname')) ?>"
                   name="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFieldName('firstname')) ?>"
                   value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getObject()->getFirstname()) ?>"
                   title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getStoreLabel('firstname')) ?>"
                   class="letters-only input-text <?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getAttributeValidationClass('firstname')) ?>" <?php if ($block->getAttributeValidationClass('firstname') == 'required-entry') echo ' data-validate="{required:true}"' ?>>
```

Last Name:-

```
<input type="text" id="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFieldId('lastname')) ?>"
                   name="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFieldName('lastname')) ?>"
                   value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getObject()->getLastname()) ?>"
                   title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getStoreLabel('lastname')) ?>"
                   class="letters-only input-text <?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getAttributeValidationClass('lastname')) ?>" <?php if ($block->getAttributeValidationClass('lastname') == 'required-entry') echo ' data-validate="{required:true}"' ?>>
```

Now **letters-only** validation only accept letter in first name and last name, not numeric value.

Comment: It's working! Thanks.

Comment: This is a nice an simple way to do a client side validation, but if the user really wants to, he/she can bypass this client side validation and actually fill in whatever for the firstname and lastname. You need a server side validation also. Unfortunately, I don't know exactly where the customer data validation happens. I just wanted to point this up as it might help have this in mind